# PyQt: Mixin that inherits from typing.Protocol : metaclass conflict: must be a subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Tags: python, pyqt, mypy

I am using PyQt and [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for type checking. When I create a mixin class for a [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtWidgets/QWidget.html) or a QMainWindow I use [typing.Protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) to satisfy mypy, but then I get a run time error instead:

```
$ ./main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hakon/test/python/pyqt/./main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from window import Window
  File "/home/hakon/test/python/pyqt/window.py", line 7, in <module>
    class Window(QMainWindow, ResizeWindowMixin):
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

**main.py**:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import logging
import sys

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication

from window import Window

def main() -> None:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    config = {'X': '100', 'Y': '100', 'Width': '500', 'Height': '500'}
    window = Window(config)
    window.show()
    app.exec()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**window.py**:

```
from mixin import ResizeWindowMixin

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QMainWindow

class Window(QMainWindow, ResizeWindowMixin):
    def __init__(self, config: dict[str, str]) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.window_config = config
        self.setWindowTitle("Test Window")
        widget = QLabel("Hello world!")
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.resize_window_from_config()
```

**mixin.py**:

```
from typing import Protocol

# from PyQt6.QtCore import QMetaObject

class ConfigWindow(Protocol):
    window_config: dict[str, str]

    def move(self, x: int, y: int) -> None:
        ...

    def resize(self, w: int, h: int) -> None:
        ...


class ResizeWindowMixin(ConfigWindow):
    def resize_window_from_config(self: ConfigWindow) -> None:
        if ("X" in self.window_config) and ("Y" in self.window_config):
            self.move(
                int(self.window_config["X"]),
                int(self.window_config["Y"]),
            )
        self.resize(int(self.window_config["Width"]), int(self.window_config["Height"]))
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: In the simplest case remove the inheritance from `ConfigWindow`.